# UITableView on top of MapView in Swift iOS-App

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, tableview

I'm relatively new to Swift, so any help is appreciated!

I‘m searching for a way to use a pull up UITableView on top of a MapView, just like it is in the Apple Maps App. Instead of the search bar I would like to have a title, but that is a next step.
I couldn‘t find any guide on how to do anything like this on the internet, so even if you just have a guess leading in the right direction, I would be thankful!
Right now I have a map view inside a NavigationController inside a TabBarController.
Unfortunately I can’t post pictures, as this is my first question, but it should look like this http://media.idownloadblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Apple-MAps-PArkopedia-silver-iPhone-screenshot-001.png

Answer (score 0):

just put a TableView on the MapView in your storyboard, add your constraints for how big/where you want to be and set the background to be clear color.

Nothing special to it/different than setting up a normal TableView.

Comment: I‘ve tried that, but if I put the TableView on top of the MapView it just replaces it. Also, this doesn‘t let me pull it up.